# Different Styles for Parenthetical vs Narrative format in Mendeley, Harvard referencing

Tags: citation-style

My Supervisor has pointed out that Harvard requires different in-text citation styles based on whether it is in Narrative style or Parenthetical.

> e.g.
>
> It has been emphasised that good referencing is an important academic skill (Harris, 2015).
>
> OR
>
> Harris (2015) emphasised that good referencing is an important academic skill.

Is there any way to edit the citation style to reflect this? I've been playing around with the CSL editor with no success. I'm using Mendeley Cite-O-Matic in Word.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a good answer for Word but in case you would consider using LaTeX, it's pretty easy to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

It has been emphasised that good referencing is an important academic skill \citep{doody}.\\

\citet{doody} emphasized that good referencing is an important academic skill.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: See output produced]

See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616883/how-to-cite-inline-in-the-form-name-year) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Mendeley allows different styles like this. You just have to manually edit it in the text. Mendeley allows you to do this freely, unlike some others. For example, to make your second example, move the opening bracket and delete the comma.